# How to use Contains or matches to return true?

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, compare, comparator

```
public class TestDriver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String y = "TEST RFP";  
    String z = "pvs_Test RFP";  

    boolean m = y.trim().toUpperCase().contains(z.trim().toUpperCase()); 
    boolean x = y.trim().toUpperCase().matches(z.trim().toUpperCase());
    boolean q = y.trim().toUpperCase().matches(".*\\b" + z.trim().toUpperCase() + "\\b.*");

    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(q);
  }
}
```

Tried contains, matches pattern matcher,...But none of them working.my intention is to return true since y and z contains the value.

finally i want to compare 
y = "TEST RFP" with the following values..
"TEST RFP", 
"test rfp", 
"pvs_Test RFP",
"test qa prpsl", 
"rFP  xyz" etc...since these words contain either "TEST" or "RFP" and should return true.

Comment: "my intention is to return true since y and z contains the value" What's the value?

Comment: y is shorter than z and you codes tried to see if z contains y which can only be true if z is shorter than y

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it reverse, try:

```
boolean m = z.trim().toUpperCase().contains(y.trim().toUpperCase());
//=> true
```

Since `z` is bigger string than will return true for a smaller string contained in variable `y`.

---

Based on your edited question and comments you can use:

```
for (String tok: y.toUpperCase().split("\\s+")) {
    boolean m = z.toUpperCase().contains(tok); 
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Comment: Sounds good anubhav, but how about "test db xyz"? i want to return true since it contains "test"